# Add a role from the DM with Discord Bot JS

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

I would like to be able to give a role to someone from the DMs if they say yes with the code underneath.
I can't find the solution to understand the bot to add the role on the server to the person.

```
const Discord = require ("discord.js"),
Client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["CHANNEL"], intents: [
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES
    ]
}),
yaml = require('js-yaml'), 
fs = require("fs");

var fichier = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync(`./data/keys.yml`, 'utf8'));
console.log(fichier.key)

Client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("bot opérationnel")
});

Client.on("messageCreate", message =>{
    console.log("Non");
    if (message.channel.type == 'DM') {
        console.log('Dm recieved!')
     }
        if (message.content == "yes"){
            console.log("ok");
        }
});

Client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
    member.send("Bienvenue, possédez-vous une clé d'activation ? Si oui envoyer la dans le channel");
});
```

Comment: What version of discord.js are you on?

Comment: My version is 13.5

Comment: What is your issue exactly? Do you receive any messages?

Comment: I can't find in version 13 of discord.js how to add a role on a server from a DM?

Comment: You have to have a specific server ID and role ID to do that

Comment: I have everything, I just need the code to do this

Comment: First, get the guild using `<Client>.guilds.get("<server id here>")` and then from the guild, get the member using `<Guild>.members.cache.get("<user id here>")` and after that call add() on it `<GuildMember>.add("<role id here>")`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do like this for adding a role when yes and when no

```js
let guildId = "..." // Put the guild Id here
let yesRoleId = "..." // Put the "yes" role Id here
let noRoleId = "..." // Put the "no" role Id here

Client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.channel.type === "DM") {
        let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildId)
        let toDo = false
        let role;

        if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "yes") {
            role = guild.roles.cache.get(yesRoleId)
            toDo = true
        } else if (message.content.toLowerCase() === "no") {
            role = guild.roles.cache.get(noRoleId)
            toDo = true
        }

        if (toDo = true) {
            toDo = false
            guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).roles.add(role)
            console.log(`Le role ${role.name} a été ajouté à ${message.author.tag}`)
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I have an error :
guild.members.cache.get(message.author.id).roles.add(role)
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')

Comment: Oww... Are you sure you have the good Intents when you create your Client ?

Comment: I have :
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES

Comment: Try `guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.id === message.author.id).first().roles.add(role)`

Comment: Same mistake, I think we can't xD

Comment: Oww... I don't really now how to fix that... Are you sure the bot is logged in, that the bot is admin on the server and that the bot have the MANAGE_ROLES permission ?

Comment: I am sure we can do that... I already tried that

Comment: From the server I can do it but from the DMs, the bot can't give roles